# Pagination in AngularUI Bootstrap doesn't shows up

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with pagination in my app. I did it in AngularUI Bootstrap with example from here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and pagination doesn't works - like in title, doesn't shows up on page.

My module in App.js

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.modal', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ui.bootstrap.pagination']);
```

Added scripts:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Example total items and page:

```
$scope.pagin = {
    totalItems: 20,
    currentPage: 1
}
```

and code in html:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="text-center">
                <uib-pagination total-items="pagin.totalItems" max-size="8" ng-model="pagin.currentPage"></uib-pagination>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: appears to work fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHfoE1FmeJLvCIRWdwww?p=preview

Comment: you don't need to add both `.js` files, either `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` or `ui-bootstrap.js`

Comment: This may be the reason?

Comment: @haxxxton thanks it works, but i don't know why it didn't work earlier with  ui-bootstrap-tpls.js